# How could I hide Redgate sql compare licenced serial number at console execution?

Tags: database-project, redgate, sqlcompare

How could I hide sql compare licenced serial number at console command execution?

Command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Red Gate\SQL Compare 11\SQLCompare.exe" /project:aaa.scp" /filter:"bbb.scpf" /scriptfile:"ccc.sql" /force /report:"ddd.xml"
```

Output logs..

```
SQL Compare: activated, edition: professional, serial number: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
SQL Compare Command Line V11.5.2.509 
============================================================================== 
Copyright Copyright � 1999 - 2016 Red Gate Software Ltd

Registering data sources 
Creating mappings 
Comparing 
Summarizing Project Selections 
Retrieving migration scripts 
Generating report 
Checking for identical databases 
Creating SQL 
Saving SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Mask Passwords Plugin with Jenkins. So I integrated this to Jenkins. Problem solved for me.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin